# How to make fixed full width horizontal lines in the Grid box around the content which has defined Padding within the box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am creating a grid box columns in HTML5 & Scss and facing an issue regarding the horizontal lines that aligned in the middle of content. My grid boxes has padding all around the content and there are two lines with full width. I tried to manage with **Positions** but when the content increases the lines move from its original positions. I need to make it fixed even when the content increases.

```
Kindly check the codepen content for better understanding - https://codepen.io/Akkanksha1/pen/ZEbVRJd
```

[this is the final output required. the section is highlighted in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acK1z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer - 
HTML

```
<div class="course-grid-wrapper">
   <div class="courses-col">
       <div class="courses-box">
           <div class="image">
               <img src="images/brandon.jpg" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="courses-content">
                <div class="course-detail">
                    <h4>Production planning process(overview)</h4>
                    <h6><span><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Deepak ladha</h6>
            </div>
            <ul class="course-date-time">
               <li><span><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>May</li>
                <li><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 10 Hours</li>
            </ul>
             <button class="btn enroll-btn">Enroll</button>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Scss -

```
.course-grid-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: rem(0 -15px 30px -15px);
    .courses-col{
        width: 25%;
        padding: rem(0 15px);
        margin-bottom: rem(30px);
        .courses-box{
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            .image{
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                padding: rem(10px 10px);
                img{
                    display: block;
                    max-width: 110px;
                    height: 110px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
            }
            .courses-content{
                .course-detail{
                    padding: rem(15px);
                    h4{
                        color: #000;
                    }
                    h6{
                        margin: rem(15px 0 15px 0);
                        color: #9D9D9D;
                        span {
                            margin-right: 5px;
                        }
                    }
                }
                .course-date-time{
                    /*margin: rem(15px 0 15px 0);*/
                    padding: 0;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
                    li {
                        list-style-type: none;
                        font-size: rem(14px);
                        color: $color-gray;
                        border-right: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
                        padding: rem(15px);
                        span {
                            margin-right: rem(5px);
                        }
                        &:last-child {
                            border-right: none;
                            &:after {
                                display: none;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .enroll-btn{
                    @include buttons($color-orange);
                    margin: .9375rem;
                    border: 2px solid $color-orange;
                    &:hover{
                        border: 2px solid $color-orange;
                        background-color: $color-white;
                        color: $color-orange;
                        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First - I removed the padding `padding: 10px 10px;` from the main class `.courses-box` and added the padding to each div in the column. for example I put all the element in Div and added the padding to div.

```
.image{
padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

Removed the padding from `.courses-content`. I put h4 and h6 heading in a div. added padding to the div.

```
.course-detail{
padding: 15px;
}
```

Where I wanted the full width horizontal lines. It become easier now. I removed the positions and added border top and bottom to ul class.

```
.course-date-time{
padding: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
}
```

For li - Added the first element border-right and added padding to each li.

```
li{
   border-right: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

Like this i achieved the full width horizontal lines around the ul.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to add width 100% in li, remove the after and add the first-child.

SCSS:

```
$color-orange: #FAA02E;
$color-gray: #757575;
$lighter-gray: #f9f9f9;
$light-gray: #fbfafa;
$dark-gray: #626262;
$color-white: #FFFFFF;

$base-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

@mixin transition ($args...) {
  -webkit-transition: $args;
  -moz-transition: $args;
  -ms-transition: $args;
  -o-transition: $args;
  transition: $args;
}
@mixin transform($transforms) {
  -webkit-transform: $transforms;
  -moz-transform: $transforms;
  -ms-transform: $transforms;
  -o-transform: $transforms;
  transform: $transforms;
}
@mixin buttons($background){
border: none;
outline: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background-color: $background;
color: $color-white;
border-radius: 29px;
line-height: 17px;
padding: 8px 50px;
cursor: pointer;
@include transition(all .6s ease);
}


.course-grid-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px 30px -15px;
    .courses-col{
        width: 25%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        .courses-box{
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            .image{
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                img{
                    display: block;
                    max-width: 110px;
                    height: 110px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
            }
            .courses-content{
                padding: 15px;
                h4{
                    color: #000;
                }
                h6{
                    margin: 15px 0 30px 0;
                    color: #9D9D9D;
                    span {
                        margin-right: 5px;
                    }
                }
                .course-date-time{
                    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    li {
                        list-style-type: none;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        color: $color-gray;
                        width: 100%;

                        span {
                            margin-right: 5px;
                        }


                        &:first-child{
                          border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
                        }
                    }
                    &:before, &:after{
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 1px;
                        background-color: #ccc;
                    }
                    &:before{
                        top: 229px;
                    }
                    &:after{
                        bottom: 83px;
                    }
                }
                .enroll-btn{
                    @include buttons($color-orange);
                    &:hover{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

https://codepen.io/HexawebIT/pen/XWmoBQz
```

Comment: If I add Width: 100% to li. It won't work because the parent div has the padding around. The parent div "courses-content" has padding: 15px;. So the lines doesn't take the full width.

Comment: I have added ul - border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; instead of position. but still it dint take the full width. @Dario9494

Comment: @AkankshaMohanty can you show me the code in codepen?

Comment: I have mention the the codepen link - https://codepen.io/Akkanksha1/pen/ZEbVRJd